# VBA Macro to split worksheet into new work books

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to vba/macros, I created a macro that splits multiple sheets into new excel file. However, I get 1004 error when I run the macro.
[image: Error COde that I get]

[image: Debug here in the code line]

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

 Dim workbookPath As String
    workbookPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        wSheet.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbookPath & "C\Path.xlsm" & wSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note macro button I have created in sheet1 named "Part1" and want to create new files from next sheet onwards. Please help....
[image: Part 1 is where I created the button]

Comment: Something should look quite off to you in `workbookPath & "C\Path.xlsm" & wSheet.Name & "POL.xlsx"`.

Comment: well I have removed "POL." and just have put ".xlsx" still I get the same error

Comment: `C\Path.xlsm` looks quite wrong in the middle there.

Comment: then what it could be it has saved only sheet1 which has a macro! With the name "Working Macro.xlsmPart1POL" and then debug macro stopped.

Comment: Please `Debug.Print` the filename before attempting to save and double check that it is valid.

Comment: where to put Debug.Print in code

Comment: `Debug.Print workbookPath & "C\Path.xlsm" & wSheet.Name & ".xlsx"` as a separate line - do this before even trying to save, and then inspect the result in the Immediate Window.

Comment: No, it's not working same error

Comment: You need to yourself verify that the path in the Immediate Window is valid. `C\Path` does not belong in the *middle* of a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert two paths into your line of code.

Since you defined the `workbookPath` variable you don't need to use `"C\Path.xlsm"`. You need to remove `"C\Path.xlsm"` and insert `"\"` before `wSheet.Name`. see basic code below.
Comment out the Debug.Print(s) after you have used to verify.

```
Dim workbookPath As String: workbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path 'ThisWorkbook is the macro enabled workbook.

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path 'open the immediate window to varify to verify the path of the macro enabled workbook. 
    
    For Each wSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        wSheet.Copy
        
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=workbookPath & "\" & wSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
        
        'When you save a sheet as a workbook it becomes the activeworkbook
        Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"; ActiveWorkbook.Name 'use to verify the path of the new workbook.
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next wSheet

End Sub
```